# Artifactory Change Base URL through file system

Tags: url, configuration, customization, artifactory, base-url

Plenty of advice on how to change the Base URL the Artifactory Pro is running on, Custom Base URL via Rest API, etc.

However, We need to change all instances of Base URL while application is not running. So if any instance of Base URL exists in file system or Mysql db, need to update accordingly.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to that is a bit tricky. You can have an 'artifactory.config.import.xml' file under your '$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/' folder. By doing so Artifactory, upon starting will consume the file and import it as it's configuration file.

**PLEASE READ THIS PART CAREFULLY**: This is the tricky part, ***the import of this file will overwrite any existing configuration*** that you have on this Artifactory instance. Meaning that you have to hold the latest modified configuration **before** shutting down the instance.